# Best practice to handle resource path for JAR and direct RUN

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar

let me explain my problem. I use intelliJ IDE and want regularly run my gradle-project via the integrated Run->Run (^R) command.
Everything works fine as expected.

But I also want to deploy a completely built JAR file to some testers.
The problem is, that the JAR won't run properly, throwing a *NullPointerException* for not findind the proper graphic sprites, located in the resources directory.

The sprites are loaded with this code:

```
hintergrundBild = new Bild(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../sprites/Backgrounds/desert-background-looped_large.jpg"));
```

(This works perfectly for directly running the project, but not for the build JAR file).

Please check out my Project structure:
[image: Project structure]

Maybe the build.gradle file is relevant, too:

```
group 'me.myGroupName'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
} 

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes  'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class' : 'SpaceShooter.SpaceShooter'
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to load resources in a manner, that works for Running and for building the JAR as well.
I would really appreciate any help given. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`hintergrundBild = new Bild(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../sprites/Backgrounds/desert-background-looped_large.jpg"));`

What if you change this to?

`hintergrundBild = new Bild(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sprites/Backgrounds/desert-background-looped_large.jpg"));`